# ¿Cómo recorrer un array con JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estoy empezando con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) y para poder avanzar en un proyecto necesitaría resolver esta duda: ¿Cómo activo un bucle `for` sobre un Array usando JQuery?

Detallo:
El array está declarado dentro del mismo script y consiste en una lista de URLs.

Estas URLs deberán cargarse en el campo "data" de una etiqueta  que embebe su contenido dentro del documento HTML.

La idea es que con un botón de avanzar -y onclick- el usuario pueda ir visualizando en la misma página y sucesivamente esta lista de URLs.

El código que he creado hasta ahora me va directamente a la última entrada del Array, pero no genera el bucle.

```
$("#siguiente-flecha").on("click", function link(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();     
        for (i; i < pages.length; i++) {                  
            if (i >=pages.length) { i=0; }
                $("#content").attr({data:pages[i]});                 
        };  
});
```

Entiendo que usar el método each no es válido porque no se trata de recorrer elementos dentro del documento HTML, sino un array definido dentro del script.

¿Cómo podría crear este bucle? ¿O cuál es el error que estoy haciendo?

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Este es el array:

```
var pages = [ 
'http://www.lavanguardia.es',
'http://www.elperiodico.com', 
'http://www.eldiario.es',
'http://www.20minutos.es',
'http://www.elmundo.es',
'http://www.marca.com'
]

var i = 0;
```

Y esta la línea en HTML:

```
<div id="main-frame">
<object id="content" type="text/html" data="http://www.elpais.com"> </object></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Cómo podría crear este buble?

En realidad no necesitas crear un `bucle`, sino que necesitas ir "guardando" en una variable la referencia a la web a mostrar y para lograr que sea una "navegación cíclica" (que vuelve a empezar cuando se llega a la última) puedes hacer uso del operar de modulo (`%`).

> ¿O cuál es el error que estoy haciendo?

El error es que usas `for` y el resultado que obtienes es recorrer por completo el arreglo `pages` en lugar de ir recorriendolo a medida que el usuario hace `click`

Para resolverlo, podrías hacer lo siguiente.

```js
$(function() {
  var pageIndex = 0; // Variable donde guardamos la ref a la proxima web a mostrar
  var pages = [ 
    'http://www.lavanguardia.es',
    'http://www.elperiodico.com', 
    'http://www.eldiario.es',
    'http://www.20minutos.es',
    'http://www.elmundo.es',
    'http://www.marca.com'
  ];
  var next = $("#siguiente-flecha");
  
  next.on("click", function link(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();     
    $("#content").attr({data:pages[pageIndex]});
    
    // Usando % (operador de modulo) logramos hacer una navegación "ciclica"
    pageIndex = (pageIndex + 1) % pages.length;
  });
  
  // Inicializamos el <object>
  next.click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-frame">
  <object id="content" type="text/html"></object>
</div>
<button id="siguiente-flecha">Siguiente</button>
```